# How to call a function based on a variable from an object within the same class?

Tags: php

I know how to call a function based off a variable like this:

```
$platform->ConfigurePlatform($client);
```

Where `$platform` is a variable which contains the name of the class.

I am trying to call a function like this, but object based from within the same class. The below will work fine, which is fine for within the same method.

```
$platform = new $platform_name();
$platform->ConfigurePlatform($client);
```

But I want to call another method within the object like this:

```
$this->$platform->GetOrdersFromPlatform();
```

This will give the error below:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property (On the line above)

I thought maybe I should create the object like this instead:

```
$this->$platform = new $platform_name();
```

However this gives the error below:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property (On the line above)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try this : $this->${$platform}->GetOrdersFromPlatform();

Comment: Thanks, but same error.

Comment: Why are you using `$this`? Shouldn't it just be `$platform->GetOrdersFromPlatform();`?

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: And if you want to create an instance of a class, then it should be: `$platform=` not `$this->$platform`

Comment: @simon Missed that out of the question, when I do this, I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function GetOrdersFromPlatform() on a non-object`

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni That's what I am doing. 5.3.1

Comment: You should use a design pattern factory https://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html

Comment: I've worked out what I am doing wrong. I have no idea why I am trying to set the name of the object as a varible. Simply doing `$this->platform = new $platform_name();` will work for my needs. It's just I won't know the name of every platform as they will be coded by others later.

Comment: I understood the question wrong, I think I understand it now. You want the object platform that was used somewhere else to be still used in the same object, is that it?

Comment: Yes that's it. I'm still learning so I struggle with the terminology a bit.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens. If you know you are gonna be using an instance of another object for multiple operations, you should definitely consider adding it to an attribute of the initial class... that way you might keep doing operations on it without losing it's reference. This is a very standard practice on OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but I think what you want is method chaining, this can be done by return the `$this` property of the class. Example:

```
class ClassName
{
    function ConfigurePlatform($client)
    {
        // What to do
        echo __METHOD__.": ".$client."\n";

        // return the $this property to make the class properties chainable
        return $this;
    }

    function GetOrdersFromPlatform($client)
    {
        // What to do
        echo __METHOD__.": ".$client."\n";

        // return the $this property to make the class properties chainable
        return $this;
    }
}


$classObj = new ClassName();

$client = "Firefox/Chrome/Safari";

// Call both methods

$classObj->ConfigurePlatform($client)->GetOrdersFromPlatform($client);
//ClassName::ConfigurePlatform: Firefox/Chrome/Safari ClassName::GetOrdersFromPlatform: Firrefox/Chrome/Safari
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for writing this. I've learnt something, however it's not what I were trying to do. I actually have two classes, one of the classes creates an object of the second class. I was just trying to make another call to the second class from another method on the first class.

Comment: Ok thanks, so please can you explain better what you need?

Comment: Surprisingly, what he wanted was much more simple than we expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the same object in different places of the class, you just need to set it into an attribute of the same class.

```
class Station
{
    public $platform = null;

    public function start()
    {
        $this->platform = new Platform();

        $this->platform->ConfigurePlatform('test');
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->platform->GetOrdersFromPlatform();
    }
}

class Platform
{
    private $orders = null;

    public function ConfigurePlatform($string)
    {
        $this->orders = $string;

        return $this;
    }

    public function GetOrdersFromPlatform()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }
}


$test = new Station();
$test->start();

echo $test->platform->GetOrdersFromPlatform();
//or
echo $test->getOrders();
```

This is the code tested: https://3v4l.org/UuTgb

Comment: Ok nice, but the OP said `based from within the same class`.

Comment: $this->platform->ConfigurePlatform is being called by the same class, I just put it down as an example, but ok, let's fix it.